# Unrecognized Selector Issue in PageViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipageviewcontroller

[image]

I am making simple intro screen. the screen slides on swipe but I want also swipe the intro screens with button tap but when I tap next button it shows an error.

complete code

```
 #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

  #import "WalkthroughPageViewController.h"

@interface WalkthroughContentViewController : UIViewController


@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *pageLbl;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *nextBtn;

@property(strong,nonatomic)WalkthroughPageViewController *pageVC;
@property NSUInteger index;
@property NSString *heading;


@end
```

**WalkthroughContentViewController.m**

```
 #import "WalkthroughContentViewController.h"


@interface WalkthroughContentViewController ()

@end

@implementation WalkthroughContentViewController



- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.pageLbl.text = self.heading;


    switch (self.index) {
        case 0:
       case 1:
            [self.nextBtn setTitle:@"Next" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            break;
        case 2:
            [self.nextBtn setTitle:@"Done" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        break;

    default:
        break;
}


}

- (IBAction)nextBtn:(id)sender {


    switch (self.index) {
        case 0:
            case 1:
            self.pageVC  = ((WalkthroughPageViewController*)self.parentViewController);


            [self.pageVC forward:self.index];
            break;
        case 2:

            [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"LoginScreen" sender:nil];

            break;

        default:
            break;
     }



}



@end
```

**WalkthroughPageViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface WalkthroughPageViewController :UIPageViewController<UIPageViewControllerDataSource>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIPageViewController *pageViewController;

@property NSArray *pageHeading;

-(void)forward:(NSUInteger)index;

@end
```

**WalkthroughPageViewController.m**

```
    #import "WalkthroughPageViewController.h"
 #import "WalkthroughContentViewController.h"

@interface WalkthroughPageViewController ()

@end

@implementation WalkthroughPageViewController


NSUInteger indexP;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
      [super viewDidLoad];

  self.pageHeading = @[@"page1",@"page2",@"page3"];

    self.pageViewController = [[UIPageViewController alloc] init];

    self.pageViewController.dataSource = self;

    WalkthroughContentViewController *startingViewController = [self viewControllerAtIndex:0];
    NSArray *viewControllers = @[startingViewController];
    [_pageViewController setViewControllers:viewControllers direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward animated:NO completion:nil];



   [self addChildViewController:self.pageViewController];
  [self.view addSubview:self.pageViewController.view];
 [self.pageViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];




}



- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerBeforeViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{

indexP  = ((WalkthroughContentViewController*) viewController).index;

if ((indexP == 0) || (indexP == NSNotFound)) {
    return nil;
}

indexP--;


    return [self viewControllerAtIndex:indexP];

}

- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerAfterViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
 {
indexP = ((WalkthroughContentViewController*) viewController).index;

if (indexP == NSNotFound) {
    return nil;
}

indexP++;
if (indexP == [self.pageHeading count]) {
    return nil;
}

    return [self viewControllerAtIndex:indexP];



}


- (WalkthroughContentViewController *)viewControllerAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index
{
if ((index == NSNotFound) || (index >= [self.pageHeading count])) {
    return nil;
}

// Create a new view controller and pass suitable data.
WalkthroughContentViewController *pageContentViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"WalkthroughContentViewController"];
pageContentViewController.heading = self.pageHeading[index];

pageContentViewController.index = index;

return pageContentViewController;
}

- (NSInteger)presentationCountForPageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController
{
return [self.pageHeading count];
}

- (NSInteger)presentationIndexForPageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController
{
return 0;
}


-(void)forward:(NSUInteger)index{


    [self.pageViewController  setViewControllers:@[[self viewControllerAtIndex:index]] direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward animated:YES completion:nil];
}


@end
```

**Error:: **

```
    [UIPageViewController forward:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

Comment: You haven't set the custom class so you have a UIPageViewController instance rather than an instance of subclass

Comment: what should i do here so the next button also swipe the screens